# A triangle is cut into several triangles, one isosceles (not equilateral) and the rest equilateral. Determine the angles of the original triangle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, triangulation

This question has been taken from **III GEOMETRICAL OLYMPIAD IN HONOUR OF I.F.SHARYGIN**:

> A triangle is cut into several (not less than two) triangles. One of them is isosceles (not equilateral), and all others are equilateral.
> Determine the angles of the original triangle.

My attempts:
I have tried solving it by cutting the original triangle into several triangles.
Each time either I end up with all equilateral triangles or my sum of angles of original triangle gets more than 180 degree.

Any idea how to solve this?

Source: [Sharygin 2007-19](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2qYu535vGeQZVphbXRSdlNreDQ/view?resourcekey=0-Heuh7IrB63TIwsH6v7ML4Q)

Comment: 30°-60°-90° works.

Comment: Please attach a link to the olympiad and/or confirm in some other way that it has been completed. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: None of the angles of the isosceles triangle is $60^\circ$. Show further that if the vertex angle is not $120^\circ$, then it must be the entire vertex of the original triangle, and then reach a contradiction.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you so much . My mistake was that I started with 3 triangles instead of 2  :D .

Comment: @CalvinLin I think its only true if we cut triangle into 3 or more than 3 triangles .

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer hey, I have now attached the link to the source. Thanks for telling .

Comment: @curious Think about the angles. If it's not at a vertex, then it's either at an edge of an interior point. The equilateral triangles must then contribute to get to $180^\circ, 360^\circ$, so is that possible? $\quad$ Then, if it's not an entire vertex. think about how we can extend the length (we can't). So this means we have to put another equilateral triangle at the vertex. What happens then?